# SELECT MAX() vs SELECT column ORDER BY column DESC LIMIT 1

Tags: mysql, database, performance, optimization

sources said that the aggregate function MAX() has a better performance that select order desc limit 1

but after executing the query from a table with 43000 records, MAX() takes about 1.5 seconds and the other takes 350ms

and when both are used in inner queries, for about 1 minute MAX() is still executing while the other yield results for 94ms

can anyone enlighten me? I'd really appreciate it

Comment: are you using a localhost server and for how many times you have tried these queries?

Answer (score 2):

It is all about the `INDEX`es and the keys that you use. use `EXPLAIN` to see where your bottlenecks are - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html.